# Segmentation Fault From Using 2D Array in Function (probably)

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

Edit3: Added Example.

Edit2: So, because I am new to coding in general and because of the current comments,I need to ask, would it be better if I posted the entire code as a comment? (around 90 lines)

So, I have been playing around with dynamic memory allocation and I have a 2D board, witch fills with '.'. Then I import the board in a function, witch checks for available cells (cell with '.'==available). It compiles ok, but when I run it I get

`segmentation fault`

Here's the code for the board malloc

```
**board = (char**) malloc(x_input*sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i <x_input; i++){
    board[i] = (char*) malloc(y_input*sizeof(char));
}

for (i = 0; i<x_input; i++){
    for(j = 0; j<y_input; j++){
        board[i][j]='.';
    }
}
```

Here's the Function

```
int checker(int x_axis, int y_axis, char **board){         
    if (board[x_axis][y_axis] == '.'){
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return 2; 
    }
}
```

And here's the only time(so far) that I call the function
Edit: `x_replacement` and `y_replacement` are assigned random values through a rand function

```
do{
    board[x_replacement][y_replacement] = '$';  
} while(checker(x_replacement, y_replacement, board) == 2);
```

EX:

```
  const int MAX_X = 40;
  const int MAX_Y = 40;
  const int MIN_X = 20;
  const int MIN_Y = 20;
  int x_input, y_input;

  int main(void){
    char **board;
    int i, j, k, obstacles, enemies, choice;

    do{
        printf("Enter board size. (Must be between (%d, %d) and (%d, %d))\n:", MIN_X, MIN_Y, MAX_X, MAX_Y);
        scanf("%d%d", &x_input, &y_input);
    }while ((x_input <= MIN_X && x_input >= MAX_X) && (y_input <= MIN_Y && y_input >= MAX_Y));

   *board = malloc(sizeof(char[x_input][y_input]));
    assert(*board != NULL);

    for (i = 0; i<x_input; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<y_input; j++){
            board[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] our question to show us a [mcve]. When and where do you have the first code-snippet? When and where and with what arguments do you call the `checker` function? And as a newcomer here please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: While not forgetting the minimal part of your [mcve], making it reproducible is also rather important. How are the first and last code snippets related? How are they placed in relation to each other? What are the initial values for `x_replacement` and `y_replacement`?

Comment: Hint: `**board = (char**) malloc(x_input*sizeof(char*));` in terms of an equation of types is `char = char**`. See anything wrong with that? It might not be your only problem, but it is definitely the first thing you should fix since `char` likely has a range up to 127 or 255 on your machine while `char**` (or any pointer) has a range up to 4294967295 or higher.

Comment: `**board = (char**) ...` will not compile cleanly on a standard C compiler. So if it did even without warnings, malloc is the least of your problems.

Comment: Update: Can someone explain to me why `board = (char**)...` does not work, since this is the way to malloc int arrays (or so I am taught in uni rn)

Comment: Probably some syntax error since you don't seem to post the actual code. But regardless of that, this isn't the correct way to allocate 2D int arrays either. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Depending on the type of `board` (which you don't actually show us) then `board = malloc(...)` might work fine. But `**board = malloc(...)` should not. Please let us stop guessing, and show us a proper [mcve].

Comment: Oh and also please read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Your new code is better, but doesn't match what you initially told us (the first code snippet). It also won't work since you dereference the uninitialized pointer `board`.

Answer (score 0):

I approached this from a different perspective, thanks to Ludin's and Some Programmer Dude's links so the result, witch works is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void arr_alloc (size_t x, size_t y, char(**board)[x][y])
{
  *board= malloc( sizeof(char[x][y]) ); 
  assert(*board!= NULL);
}

void arr_fill (size_t x, size_t y, char board[x][y])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
    {
      array[i][j] = '.';
    }
  }
}

void arr_print (size_t x, size_t y, char board[x][y])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
    {
      printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main (void)
{
    int x,y;
    char (*board)[x][y];
    printf("enter dimentions: \n");
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);



  arr_alloc(x, y, &board);
  arr_fill(x, y, *board);
  arr_print(x, y, *board);
  free(board); 

  return 0;
}
```